# Compiling UniProt txt file into a dict to retrieve key (ID) and values (MOD_RES)

Tags: python, regex, flat-file

I am not much familiar with python and trying to retrieve data from a text file(test1), Uniprot, that looks like this:

ID   YSH1_YEAST              Reviewed;         779 AA.

AC   Q06224; D6VYS4;

DT   10-JAN-2006, integrated into UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot

DT   01-NOV-1996, sequence version 1.

.

.

.

FT   METAL       184    184       Zinc 1. {ECO:0000250}.

FT   METAL       184    184       Zinc 2. {ECO:0000250}.

FT   METAL       430    430       Zinc 2. {ECO:0000250}.

FT   MOD_RES     517    517       Phosphoserine; by ATM or ATR.

FT                                {ECO:0000244|PubMed:18407956}.

FT   MUTAGEN      37     37       D->N: Loss of endonuclease activity.

.

.

So far I am able to retrieve the MOD_RES and AC separately, by using these codelets:

test = open('test1', 'r')

regex2 = re.compile(r'^AC\s+\w+')

for line in test:

```
ac = regex2.findall(line)

for a in ac:

    a=''.join(a)

    print(a[5:12])
```

Q06224

P16521

testfile = open('test1')

regex = re.compile(r'^FT\s+\MOD_RES\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w.+')

for line in testfile:

```
po = regex.findall(line)

for p in po:

    p=''.join(p)

    print(p[23:48])
```

517       Phosphoserine;

2       N-acetylserine

187       N6,N6,N6-trime

196       N6,N6,N6-trime

the goal is to get AC and their relevant Modification residues (MOD_RES) into a tab separate format. Also, if more than one MOS_RES appear in the data for a particular AC, duplicate that AC and get the table format like this:

AC  MOD_RES

Q06224  517    517       Phosphoserine

P04524  75    75       Phosphoserine

Q06224  57    57       Phosphoserine

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc121)?

You should be able to parse your Uniprot file like that:

```
from Bio import SwissProt
for record in SwissProt.parse(open('/path/to/your/uniprot_sprot.dat')):
  for feature in record.features:
    print feature
```

From there you should be able to print what you want to a file.